# Convert GNU-CRYPTO gkr keystore to default JKS

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I've a keystore with a private key in gnu-crypto gkr format. It was created using gkeytool. I need to be able to use this key with the standard JRE tools so is there any way to convert from GKR to standard JKS?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution. It can be done by exporting the private key and importing it in  a new JKS keystore. However, to export the private key from the GKR keystore is not trivial but this post can be used to get some inspiration ;)

http://www.commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art006

Comment: This doesn't tell how you did it.

Comment: I created a simple Java class implementing the algorithm described in the article and used it to extract the private key.